# Partial effect interpretation and zero conditional mean assumption

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, econometrics, regression-coefficients

Let's say we have the following population equation.

$$
y = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{2} + u
$$

Then to explain the interpretation of $\beta_{1}$ or $\beta_{2}$, we can look at the partial changes.

$$
\Delta y = \beta_{1} \Delta x_{1} + \beta_{2} \Delta x_{2} + \Delta u
$$

Now, `holding all other factors fixed` essentially means $\Delta x_{2}=0$ for $\beta_{1}$. But how do we guarantee $\Delta u=0$?

I was thinking the zero conditional mean assumption($E[u|x_{1},x_{2}]=0$) should play a role, but this is saying that conditional on covariates, the average of error term is zero. It doesn't necessarily mean $\Delta u =0$.

How should I get that $\beta_{1}$ is a partial effect of $x_{1}$ on y from the equation on partial changes?

Comment: Divide through by $\Delta x_1$

Comment: @dimitriy But then we have $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \beta_{1} + \frac{\Delta u }{\Delta x}$. We still have the later term....

Comment: That's where the independence assumption comes in. Do you expect $u$ to change when $x_1$ moves?

Comment: @dimitriy But I thought, the $E[u|x]=0$ is mean independence, not full independence? If it is full independence I can understand. But isn't this assumption saying that expected value of errors are zero regardless of what value x is? BTW thank you so much for replying :)

Comment: Regression estimates a conditional mean, so mean independence is sufficient, I think. So $\Delta y$ is really $\Delta E[y \vert x_1, x_2]$.

Comment: @dimitriy I see. I also agree that for OLS estimators where we essentially get the averages conditioning on covariates, we can use conditional expectation. So I understand that $\hat{\beta}_{1}$ is the partial effect using the above formula. But then is it wrong to say that the true unknown $\beta_{1}$ is the partial effect?

Comment: @dimitriy But then again, for OLS estimators we are dividing $y$ with fitted value and residuals who is by design orthogonal... So I don't have hard time understanding the partial interpretation of the OLS estimators. I guess I am somewhat confused about how to interpret the true parameter...?